# Dax rolling 30 days with SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I want to visualize 2 trends in Power BI with rolling revenue for 30 days

- First trend - actual day
- Second trend - SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR

I have a problem with last day for the Second trend (wrong calculation)
My steps for calculate Second trend:

1. `Revenue PY = CALCULATE([Revenue Act];SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[Date]))`
2. `Revenue PY (30d) = CALCULATE(revenue_v1[Revenue PY];FILTER(ALL('Calendar');'Calendar'[Index]>MAX('Calendar'[Index])-30&&'Calendar'[Index]<=MAX('Calendar'[Index])))`

What I am doing wrong?

[image]